# PHP / MySql - как в запрос поставить условие

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть запрос к базе, который ищет пользователя, и есть вот такой код:

```
if ($Row['uid'] == $_SESSION['id']) $Friend = $Row['inid'];
else $Friend = $Row['uid'];
```

Мне нужно чтобы это условие работало в запросе к базе.

Вот мой старый код:

```
$Result = mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT id, uid, inid, date FROM friend WHERE (uid = $_SESSION['id'] AND inactive = 1 AND unactive = 1) OR (inid = $_SESSION['id'] AND unactive = 1 AND inactive = 1) ORDER BY date DESC ');
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
    if ($Row['uid'] == $_SESSION['id']) $Friend = $Row['inid'];
    else $Friend = $Row['uid'];`

    `$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT id, name, family, avatar, town FROM users WHERE id = $Friend AND online > now() ") );
```

А вод новый:

```
<?
 $Result = mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT friend.id, friend.uid, <br>friend.inid, friend.date, users.id, users.name, users.family, users.avatar, users.town
        FROM 
            friend LEFT JOIN users ON (`friend`.`uid`=`users`.`id`)
        WHERE 
            friend.inactive = 1
            AND friend.unactive = 1
            AND users.online > now()')
```

Алгоритм кода такой:

ищем в таблице friend ид пользователя при условии:
где `inid = $_SESSION['id']` или `uid = $_SESSION['id']` и где `inactive=1` и `unactive=1`
если `inid = $_SESSION['id']` тогда вытаскиваем `uid`
если `uid = $_SESSION['id']` вытаскиваем `inid`
тогда по тому списку, который получился ид ищем пользователей в таблице `users` одинаковые ид при условии:
когда поле `online+15минут > NOW()`

В общем выводим список пользователей(друзей) онлайн.

Comment: В MySQL есть функция `IF()` что то вроде `IF(uid=XXX,inid,uid)`

Comment: Лучше CASE - он универсален.

Comment: можно пример? 
я не особо знаю эти функции)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html